# SOAP web service works only with PHP?

Tags: java, php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am using a SOAP webservice that is supposed to work with Java, PHP and a lot of technologies. However, it is only working correctly with PHP.

I used the SOAPClient class in PHP to implement the client. When I printed the request and response headers, I got something like this:

```
REQUEST HEADERS:
POST /ws/something.php HTTP/1.1
Host: xxx.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: PHP-SOAP/5.5.30
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "http://example.com/ws/something.php/someMethod"
Content-Length: 417
Authorization: Basic <username:password here>


RESPONSE HEADERS:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 03 Mar 2016 18:03:48 GMT
Server: Apache
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload
Content-Length: 512049
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Set-Cookie: BALANCEID=balancer.<someIP>; path=/; HTTPOnly; Secure
Keep-Alive: timeout=2, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Then, I used SAAJ in Java to write the exact same request like how PHP does it. I edited even the user-agent to make it exact, but I have no luck. The response is always the SOAP service's wsdl. For some reason, the web service does not execute anything if I use Java.

These are the request headers for Java:

```
Authorization   Basic <username:password here>
SOAPAction  http://example.com/ws/something.php/someMethod
POST /ws/something.php HTTP/1.1
Host     xxx.com
Connection  Keep-Alive
User-Agent  PHP-SOAP/5.5.30
Content-Type    text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length  417
```

This is the response header:

```
Date    Thu
Date    03 Mar 2016 18:24:35 GMT
Server  Apache
Strict-Transport-Security   max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload
Accept-Ranges   none
Vary     Accept-Encoding
Vary     User-Agent
Content-Type     text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Set-Cookie  BALANCEID=balancer.<some IP>; path=/; HTTPOnly; Secure
Keep-Alive  timeout=2
Keep-Alive  max=100
Connection  Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
Content-Length  8444
SOAPAction  ""
```

Note how the response header is completely different.

I have no idea why the web service won't execute the exact same request from Java. It just returns the wsdl. Does that mean something is wrong with my request or does the web service magically work only with PHP soapClient?

Comment: I this the actual order of the headers in your HTTP request? If so, I believe that the first line of a valid [HTTP request](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-3.1.1) should be the method (in your case, POST) line.

Comment: @carl-groner I moved it to the front. But, it still doesn't work. I don't believe that is the reason. The data is posting to the web service because it returns the wsdl of the web service.